# [meteor][0.6.*] How to dynamically write file in meteorjs without restarting app

Tags: meteor

Hy,

my app needs to write file in the app folder. The problem is what you know : Meteor restart the app when any file is created/modified/deleted. 
So how can we do that features ?

i know that some write the file in a folder that is outside the app folder. But i cannot.
i tryed to add ~ at the end or the beginning, but that not for this kind of features (it only means that the file is static).

Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on what you are trying to accomplish? What kind of file are you trying to write and why?

Comment: I just want to save image from a url and store it on the filesystem to do a backup of the file. Image are only thumbnail so less than 5Ko each.
In my process i store all url and i download/write on file systme only at the end. But because of the app restart, only the first one is saved. And i don't really like to restart the app.

Comment: In fact i'm able to write in .meteor folder but that's not really cool and clean.
The best thing would be to know how the refresh work to exclude some specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why it doesn't work the first time but adding a "~" at the end of a folder will exclude it from live spying.
So i created a "public/img/myfolder~" and it works well without hacking the core.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude files from being watched in the bundler.js file, which is located under:
/Users/yourUserName/.meteor/tools/latest/tools/bundler.js on mac os x (assuming you are using the latest build).
around line 50 you find the following code block:

```
// files to ignore when bundling. node has no globs, so use regexps

    var ignore_files = [
        /~$/, /^\.#/, /^#.*#$/,
        /^\.DS_Store$/, /^ehthumbs\.db$/, /^Icon.$/, /^Thumbs\.db$/,
        /^\.meteor$/, /* avoids scanning N^2 files when bundling all packages */
        /^\.git$/, /* often has too many files to watch */

        /^\public$/ /* myEDIT: that's how you can exclude the public dir */

    ];
```

This is valid for all you meteor apps in development mode. 
Good luck

Comment: Which version of Meteor do you use ? i'm on 0.6.* and i d'ont have this file.

Comment: I'm on mac os x 10.8.3, a$ meteor --version, Release 0.6.3.1. Try searching for bundler.js if you are on a different OS

Comment: i've looked for that file and also for ignore_files string using a grep. I've also tryed to do a meteor bundle and then check inside the tarball.
I'll still look for that tomorrow

Comment: I can confirm that i don't see that file neither the var ignore_files in any file.

Comment: Ok, i've finally seen the file, but it's in Meteor installation directory, not in my Meteor app. But the strange thing is that i don't find the file in the bundled version of my app. There's something i might do the wrong way.

Comment: Finally i reinstalled meteor and the ~ at the end of the folder name prevent meteor to restart.